# Quando "a fortiori" ortum est?

Tags: idiom, history, legal-latin, logic

Quando vocabulum **a fortiori** (sive *[a fortiore](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/133/118)*) ortum est ut nomen artis legis logicæve? In quo opere scripto primum apparuit?

Volo intellegere eius rationem originis verificareque verbum elisum "**ratione**" esse. (Vocabulum *a fortiore* enim idem significat ac *a ratione fortiore*.) Notionem in duobus auctoribus antiquis inveni, *[Rhetorica ad Herennium](https://archive.org/stream/adcherenniumdera00capluoft#page/292/mode/2up)* IV.18 et *[Topica](https://archive.org/stream/oratorbrutustopi00cice#page/382/mode/2up)* Ciceronis 4.23, sed in locutionibus dissimilibus, e.g. "Quod in re maiore valet, valeat in minore."

Comment: Praemium quinquaginta punctorum praebui, sed nemo respondit. Hoc interrogatum difficillimum est!

Answer (score 3):

Auctor libri qui inscribitur *Dizionario Storico-Giuridico Romano* nos refert ad philosophos medii aevi, Latham, *Wordlist*, s. v. 'a, ab' annos indicat 'c. 1337, c. 1343' sine auctorum indicatione. Exemplum inveni in Occhami *Dialogo*, III tr. 2 lib. 2 cap.1: "Magister: Ex his verbis habetur quod potestas regis Francorum distincta est a potestate papae. Et per consequens a fortiori potestas imperatoris," scilicet si potestas regi Fr. non pendet a papa, potestas imperatoris quae maior est quam regis, a papa neutiquam pendet. Elisio quaedam fortasse origini talium locutionum subest; tamen non est quod eam subaudias hoc loco.

Comment: Me pænitet tuum responsum non legisse cum proposuisti! [Subsequentem quæstionem](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/15264/118) nunc propono.