# "All the more so"

Tags: classical-latin, history, phrase-request

How, in classical Latin, did one say "all the more so" or otherwise indicate that a proposition harder than you're trying to prove has just been
proven, so your proposition must be at least as certain?

In English, we sometimes say **a fortiori** to indicate this: "Unicorns
don't exist, so, *a fortiori,* one couldn't have bitten you." I'm researching
the [origins of the term *a
fortiori*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/295/118), and so far, I have not
found the idiom *a fortiore ratione* in any Ancient Roman writing.  It seems
likely, though, that people would have *some* sort of common way of expressing
the concept.

I do know of a phrase with this meaning which occurs throughout Latin
translations of the Bible: **quanto magis**. Here are a couple examples:

> Si ergo uos cum sitis mali nostis bona data dare filiis uestris, **Quanto
> magis** pater uester de cælo dabit bona petentibus se? (Matthew 7:11, [Old
> Latin](https://books.google.com/books?id=8odbAAAAMAAJ&lpg=PA90&pg=PA90))
>
> *If ye then, being evil, know how to give good gifts unto your children,
> **how much more** shall your Father which is in heaven give good things to
> them that ask him? (KJV)*
>
> Respicite uolatili a cæli, quoniam non serunt neque metunt neque congregant in
> horreo. Et pater vester cælestis alit illas. **Nonne magis uos pluris estis
> illis?** (Matthew 6:26, [Old Latin](https://books.google.com/books?id=8odbAAAAMAAJ&lpg=PA7&pg=PA7))
>
> *Behold the fowls of the air: for they sow not, neither do they reap, nor
> gather into barns; yet your heavenly Father feedeth them. **Are ye not much
> better than they?** (KJV)*

I've read, though, that "how much more?" is a direct translation of the Hebrew
word אַף
(*[af](https://books.google.com/books?id=U4btePgZO0IC&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=%22and+how+much+more%22+bible+hebrew+rhetoric&source=bl&ots=ir0fclcXLh&sig=FmaketQE5bhaJHTxfrcS8j8mNbs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUuP2N47LLAhVsk4MKHR5bAugQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22and%20how%20much%20more%22%20bible%20hebrew%20rhetoric&f=false)*)
or וְאַף, "and how much more", commonly used in Jewish rhetoric at that time to
indicate an *a fortiori* argument. I can't tell if it's a Hebrew expression
mostly limited to Bible translations, just as in English, or if it took root in
Latin also. (Not to be confused with קַל וָחֹמֶר, *qal vachomer*, "light and
heavy", another Hebrew expression for the same kind of argument.)

To put this another way, how would
[Vitruvius](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/vitruvius7.html#5.3) say,
"Plant-stalks with animal-heads don't exist, so ⎯⎯⎯⎯ one couldn't have bitten
you"?

Answer (score 12):

I would translate the phrase "all the more" using ***eo magis***. Note that this phrase is much more common when "balanced" with an introductory phrase that introduces the comparison, usually with a comparative adverb.

Here are a few examples of usage: (hasty translations mine)

> ita, quo minus petebat gloriam, eo magis illum sequebatur. (Sallust, *The Catilinarian Conspiracy*, 54)
>
> *Thus, the less he sought glory, the more it pursued him.*

and

> quod quo studiosius absconditur, eo magis eminet
>
> *The more carefully it is hidden, the more it juts out.*

and with *atque*:

> reliquum erat certamen positum in virtute, qua nostri milites facile superabant, atque eo magis, quod in conspectu Caesaris atque omnis exercitus res gerebatur (Caesar, *De Bello Gallico*, III 14, 8)
>
> *The remaining fight depended on courage, by which our soldiers easily carried the day; all the more so because it unfolded in the sight of Caesar and the whole army.*

I believe that none of these examples quite covers the case that you are citing, which is a more direct translation of everything implied by *a fortiori*:

Here are some other options that might work:

1. ***Ex quo patet*** + acc. and inf.: *from which it is evident, etc.* (Note that I did not find classical examples of this exact phrae)
2. ***Constat ergo*** + acc. and inf.: *It is therefore certain, etc.*

or, for some good ol' classical hyperbole:

3. ***Quid dementius quam*** + inf.: *what could be more insane than* (And yes, this is probably inappropriate as a substitution for *a fortiori* 99.99% of the time.)

Comment: just to add a beautiful known example of "eo magis" (without an introductory phrase):  "quod, ut dicitur, si est homo bulla, **eo magis** senex" (Varro)

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be **nedum**. According to [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=nedum&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) it means "by no means, much less, still less, not to speak of (class.)", and more particularly for our context: **"used to indicate that whereas a certain thing is not, another thing can still less be"**.

Interestingly, my mind has hard time settling whether *nedum*, which might be well translated (and was actually translated) as *let alone*, should be considered as a synonym or rather antonym of *"all the more so"*. But eventually it does seem to be a proper fit here:

> igitur nulla simulacra urbibus suis, **nedum** templis sistunt (They therefore do not allow any images to stand in their cities, **much less** [all the more so] in their temples) [Tac.](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Tac.%20Hist.%205.5&lang=original)

> Quinctius, quem armorum etiam pro patria satietas teneret **nedum** aduersus patriam (Quinctius was sated with war, even war in behalf of his country, **to say nothing of** [all the more so] fighting against it) [Liv.](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Liv.%207.40&lang=original)

---

It might be also worth to take a look at [Latin Phrase for “It goes without saying”](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13687/latin-phrase-for-it-goes-without-saying) which is quite close (while nevertheless has perceptible differences).