# Latin Phrase for "It goes without saying"

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, idiom

The title of the question pretty much sums it up.
I am looking for a Latin phrase for the English expression "It goes without saying." I am not sure if an analogous expression exists- although I would be surprised if it didn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can say: **ex se intellegitur** (literally: *it is understood from itself*). An [alternative](http://www.zeno.org/Georges-1910/A/selbstverst%C3%A4ndlich?hl=selbstverstandlich) you will sometimes find is *per se intellegitur*.

> Ex se intellegitur me ad tempus advenisse.
> *It goes without saying that I arrived on time.*
>
> Hoc ex se intellegitur.
> *That goes without saying.*
>
> Intellegitur ex se quam laeta est.
> *I need not tell you how happy she is.*
>
> Id [argumentatio] facere oportet cum aut propositio ex se intellegitur aut assumptio perspicua est et nullius approbationis indiget. (Cicero, [De inventione, 1.70](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/inventione1.shtml#70))
> *An argument must be made unless the proposition goes without saying or the assumption is obvious and requires no proof.*

And there you have another option: **perspicuum est** (literally: *it is obvious*)

> Perspicuum est natura nos a dolore abhorrere. (Cicero, [De finibus, 3.62](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/fin3.shtml#62))
> *Obviously by our nature we dislike pain.*

Another option [I found](https://books.google.de/books?id=FQcGxoTPnwsC&pg=PA165): **hoc sua sponte apparet** (literally: *it appears of its own volition*). There are quite a few historical uses but I doubt it is classical.

Comment: If "ex se intellegetur me ad tempus advenisse." is written indirectly, why is "intellegitur ex se quam laeta est." not?

Comment: @tony because, as so often, I made a mistake: it should be *quam laeta sit*.

Comment: Sebastian Koppehel: I have been trying to find examples of subordinate clauses, in indirect speech, introduced by "quam" = "how", with no luck. In Pinkster's notes on relative clauses, p2, (freely available on the net) among all the substantives, adjectives & adverbs used for this purpose, "quam" = "how", is not one of them. Are you sure about this? I would have translated: "intellegetur ex se laetissimam esse." = "I need not tell you that she is supremely happy."

Comment: @tony Look no further than the [L & S entry for *quam*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dquam) (under letter B).

Comment: Thank you. It's an indirect question! Often puzzling because many of these are not questions at all--nobody is asking anybody anything. In Latin, it seems to be the case that if there's an interrogative with a subjunctive, it's called an indirect question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 12):

A legal expression that has this meaning is:

> Res ipsa loquitur

This literally means *the thing speaks for itself.*

Comment: This suggestion is great!