# Elisum nomen ab "a fortiori"

Tags: medieval-latin, logic

What, if anything, is the elided noun in the phrase *a fortiori*?

### A curious variant and a curious translation

I had been assuming that the full phrase is *a fortiori ratione,* "with stronger reason", but [this answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/5917/118) by @[Johann Ramminger](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/2370/johann-ramminger) just sent me to the following passage from Ockham's *Dialogus,*
part 3, tract 2, book 2, translated [here](http://publications.thebritishacademy.ac.uk/pubs/dialogus/t32d2Con.html) by John Scott, including collations from [numerous manuscripts](http://publications.thebritishacademy.ac.uk/pubs/dialogus/31Relationships.html):

[image: Quotation with collations from Dialogus, part 3, tract 2, book 2, pointing out "Ex quo concluditur quod multo fortius…" in three manuscripts]

Three of the manuscripts have the variant *concluditur quod **multo fortius**…distincta est* in place of *per consequens **a fortiori**…*. The translator appears to have favored the variant: "It is **much more the case** that…is distinct." So, the variant and translation seem to take *a fortiori* to mean that the conclusion is itself stronger, rather than that the conclusion is established with a stronger basis. This suggests that there is actually no elided noun in *a fortiori*—that the adjective is meant substantively, the phrase perhaps meaning "with greater strength".

### Reasoning and evidence?

My first thought is that the above reading is simply a mistake. The reasoning is typical *a fortiori*: since a king's power does not derive from the pope's, neither can an emperor's, since an emperor's power includes and surpasses that of a king. The subject matter primes such a mistake, since the subject matter is an explicit comparison of (legal) powers.

But I could be wrong. What textual evidence do we have that *a fortiori* is short for *a fortiori ratione*—or whatever it's short for, if anything?