# Does "a priori" have an implied substantive?

Tags: medieval-latin, logic

Is **a priori** short for a longer phrase of the form **a priori _____**? If so, what is the elided substantive?

---

**Background, or, How I Got Confused**

I'm pretty sure that **a fortiori** is short for **a fortiori ratione**. I [haven't found the origin of the phrase](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/295/118), but it seems clear from usage that there is an implied noun, and that that noun is either **ratio** or a synonym. Douglas Harper [reports](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=a+priori&allowed_in_frame=0) that **a priori** started c. 1300 to describe reasoning from a cause or first principle. That suggests to me that **a priori** might also have an implied noun, also obvious from usage and hence likely to be dropped—maybe a noun meaning "cause" or "first principle" or "antecedent".

Contemporary usage is strongly influenced by Kant, who used **a priori** as a sort of adjective for knowledge deriving from the nature of the mind rather than from the objects sensed or experienced. I had gotten the impression that the elided noun might mean something like experience, so the phrase would mean "**from before experience**". Today people often use the phrase to refer to things you can know before doing an experiment, either by deducing from already-established theory or just because you already found out; see e.g. [this paper](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/full/10.1162/neco.2008.08-07-594?select23=Choose&#.WPq3j0s8iUI) on designing neurophysiology experiments.

Now that I've been learning Latin, though, it appears that **a priori** is the start of a prepositional phrase that ends in a noun, like "from a previous _____" or "from the first _____", not capable of functioning as a sort of preposition itself, like "from before _____" or "from earlier than _____."

But I just read this in Guyer and Woods' translation notes on the *Critique of Pure Reason* (p. 74):

> Our decision [to preserve ambiguous and obscure constructions in Kant's original text wherever possible] also means that where Kant's location of the adverbial phrase "**a priori**," which he always treats as a Latin bor­rowing rather than a naturalized latinate German term, is ambiguous between **an adverbial modification of a verb** and **an adjectival modifica­tion of a noun**, we have tried to leave it ambiguous, although we could not always do so.

So does **a priori** work like **in concreto**: as a prepositional phrase with no noun? On this hypothesis, as **in concreto** means "concretely", **a priori** would mean "beforely"—except that since it's a prepositional phrase, it can modify nouns as well as verbs, i.e. serve as adjective or adverb.

Comment: I always assumed it originated in something like *a priori tempore* and *tempore* disappeared though ordinary ellipsis. But I can't prove it. // As to adverbialism: most prepositional phrases are adverbial, such as *she was in town, she stood behind him*, etc. But they can often also be used attributively, as in *the tavern in town is ugly, the house behind him is ugly*. I think this is what Kant's translators meant: at the higher (phrase) level, it can be used adverbially or attributively. But this is about the structure of the German language; not about the potentially omitted Latin word.

Comment: So I don't think the translators' comments are relevant to your question. // It is possible that *priori* is an undefined, neuter, substantively used adjective à la *concreto*, as you say. Let's hope someone comes up with something.

Comment: @Cerberus Indeed I just meant that the paragraph from Guyer and Woods gave me a new hypothesis: that _a priori_ isn't short for anything after all. I'll edit the question to clarify that this hypothesis doesn't limit the phrase to adverbial use (though I may have to kill my darling "beforely").

Answer (score 3):

Here are some scattered observations, which may or may not constitute an answer.

I found<sup>1</sup> no classical examples of *a priori*, but several examples of *a priore*<sup>2</sup>, most followed by an ablative noun.
[Pliny](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0138:book=2:chapter=17&highlight=a+priore%2C) has an *a priori* without a following noun, but there is an obvious implicit *defecto*.
([English version here.](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0137:book=2:chapter=10&highlight=thirty))

[The Rule of Benedict](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/benedict.html) has several examples of *a priore*.
In this work *prior* is practically a noun, and [this translation by Rev. Boniface Verheyen](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/benedict/rule.i.html) consistently translates it as "the Superior".
This is the earliest example I found of substantivization of *prior* (including *a priore*), and it is consistent throughout the work.
The meaning is very different from the philosophical or logical *a priori*.

It is hardly a surprise, but [Gauss](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/gauss.html) uses *a priori* in the modern sense in Latin.

Lastly, I am not sure if there is a real difference between a substantivized adjective and an adjective used with an implicit noun.
There is an effect on gender (eg. *res mala* and *malum*), but all genders look the same for *priore/priori*.
It is interesting to ask how the phrase was born — and I cannot give a convincing history on that — but after some thought I see little point in figuring out whether it is a substantivized adjective or has an implicit noun.

---

<sup>1</sup>
The search was admittedly not exhaustive.
I only looked at the texts of [The Latin Library](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/).

<sup>2</sup>
In classical Latin the third declension the singular ablative ending is (almost) always *-i* for adjectives.
In comparative (which is third declension for all adjectives) the ending is *-e*.
And if *prior* was declined like a noun, it would get the *-e*.
Therefore *a priori* with the *-i* looks like a later development.
If it was abbreviated from a phrase used by a classical author, I would expect it in the form *a priore* instead.

Comment: Actually, my closing hypothesis is that _priori_ in this phrase is not functioning as a substantivized adjective and also doesn't have an implicit noun as its object. It's functioning by analogy with similar phrases with nouns, like _in actu, in potentia, ab initio,_ etc. If this hypothesis is true, then you should be able to do it with other adjectives, too. _In concreto_ is the only other example I can think of right now. I'll post a separate question specifically about this element of grammar.

Comment: @BenKovitz I would see those phrases you list as substantivized adjectives with a preposition. But, as usual, it depends on the point of view, and mine might be different tomorrow.

Comment: About _priori_ rather than _priore_, yes, this is a medieval development (or degradation); we looked at it a bit [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/133/118). If the phrase existed in Classical times, I'd expect it to be _a priore_. So far, though, I'm assuming that _a priori_ as a sort of technical term in itself originated in the Middle Ages, so I'm using the medieval (and modern) spelling (and cringing).

Comment: @BenKovitz It takes an effort not to cringe when using *a priori* and the like in English. But too few people would appreciate changing it to *a priore*... Agreed, as the technical term in the modern sense *a priori* appears to be younger than classical.

Comment: Btw, regarding Ben's rule, even today in English Benedictine monks have a "prior."